# How to generate calendar from simple calendar gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

I am trying to generate simple calendar in my app using simple calendar gem. i have project model which has project_title, client_name, description, startdate and enddate.

i need to show the view of calendar from startdate to enddate when i open the project view.how can i do that?

Here's the code:

```
<p>
  <strong>Project title:</strong>
  <%= @project.project_title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Client name:</strong>
  <%= @project.client_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Project desc:</strong>
  <%= @project.project_desc %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Project startdate:</strong>
  <%= @project.project_startdate %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Project enddate:</strong>
  <%= @project.project_enddate %>
</p>

### here i need to get the calendar view from above startdate and enddate
```

Answer (score 1):

First fetch the difference between `:start_date` & `end_date`:

```
total_days = end_date - start_date
```

Now create a custom calender by passing some arguments:

```
<%= calendar number_of_days: total_days, start_date: start_date_of_your_project do |date| %>
  <%= date %>
<% end %>
```

Let me know! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as well!

```
<%= calendar @project.project_startdate..@project.project_enddate do |date| %>
  <%= date %>
<% end %>
```